# Mix params and nameof in method to check for nulls

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I've created a method that is intended to check for nulls and throw a `NullArgumentException` with the correct parameter name.

The method is this:

```
public static void CheckNotNull(params object[] args)
{
     // if any of the args is null
     // then Throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(…))
}
```

I'm not even sure if this is possible! Is it?

Comment: What is your difficulty?  Are you suggesting that `namesof(args)` is not working for you?

Comment: If your primary concern is to save typing: you can define [snippets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms165392) in Visual Studio that will allow you to (for example) type `notnull <TAB>` or even `nn <TAB>` that will expand to the requisite `if ([arg] == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof([arg]));`. Normally covering up boilerplate with snippets is a bad idea, but in this case there really is no shorter way of expressing this idiom for a single parameter, and stuffing them together just brings headaches when you change the signature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only parameter in this method is `args` which you can check using `nameof`:

```
public static void CheckNotNull(params object[] args)
{
    if (args == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(args))
    }
}
```

The items themselves can also be `null` but they aren't really parameters and they are nameless. You can check them too and throw an appropriate exception:

```
if (args.Any(item => item == null))
{
    throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(args)} cannot contain nulls");
}
```

Comment: So the original goal to make it throw an ArgumentNullException with the name of the parameter is not possible. Bummer :(

Comment: @SuperJMN well, `args` is the only parameter here. The items inside it are not parameters, they are items in an array which is the parameter itself.